# Is there a way to invert uppercase and lowercase in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, capslock

Sometimes, when I write a comment on Youtube for example, or searching something on Google, i don't realize that capslock is on.

While in the google case, it's not a big problem, in the youtube case it can get pretty annoying. I know that in word, you can press Shift + F3 to invert the uppercase and lowercase letters.

Is there a similar key combination in Windows 10, as I don't want to open word and change it, nor write the same comment again

Comment: You might be able to do this with a 3rd party application like Auto HotKey but it isn't available natively.

Comment: There's probably a plugin for your browser which lets you do this. A better workaround for your sanity is to disable Caps Lock.

Comment: if you want to disable capslock [which I do on all machines right from the outset ;) try https://www.wikihow.com/Disable-the-Capslock-Key-in-Windows

Comment: @tripleee While using `SHIFT` is faster to toggle uppercase, disabling Caps Lock altogether may imply to simply use all lowercase, and that's just bad all around due to being grammatically incorrect.

Comment: A workaround is to copy/paste the text into a text editor like [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io), then use the option from the menu to use Sentence Case or swap case.

Comment: @JW0914 You're not serious, right? Just shift has been sufficient for me for almost 40 years.

Comment: @tripleee Not everyone knows `SHIFT` can be used to capitalize, nor is there any way to know if the author knows that it can.  Considering the amount of questions posted to SuperUser every day without basic capitalization, I'd posit many are not aware of that.  My only point was the comment would have benefited from mentioning to use `SHIFT` in lieu of.

Comment: @JW0914 But thats the same as the part where I said if there is a key combination, so I don't need to copy and paste it into a text editor

Comment: @JW0914 - if they didn't know what shift was for, how would they ***possibly*** be getting their cases inverted in the first place. One implies the other, QED.

Comment: @Tetsujin ??? By thinking their Caps Lock is off when it's on and vice versa... Regardless, enough of my time has been wasted and this topic has moved to the ludicrous stage...

Comment: @JW0914 - You appear to be completely missing the point people are trying to correct you on. OP knows shift is used to shift case, otherwise accidental capslock wouldn't result in **inverted** case, it would just be all-caps. You can only get inverted case by having capslock on **and** also using shift where needed. Result… yOU gET tHIS kIND oF iNVERSION. It requires a typist who looks at their hands not the screen, but I see people do it every day in online chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no Windows builtin function which enables this in any program.

In some application such functionality might be implemented, as you stated in Microsoft Word you can use `Shift` + `F3`.

You could maybe accomplish this system-wide using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)